# PowerShell Azure function reference other files in script

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-function-app, azure-durable-functions

I have a function am working on, I have placed an xml file in the same folder as the function. I'm trying to get this folder using syntax like this: `./file.xml` or `~/functionfolder/file.xml` .. but nothing is working. I saw other posts online suggesting using something like this:

`$EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` .. however when I write-host `$EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` it shows nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Functions V3 and V2, `$PSScriptRoot` contains the path of the directory where the running script is located. You can refer to other files like this: `$PSScriptRoot\file.xml`. `$EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` was available in the experimental and not officially supported V1 implementation.